# problem sending html2canvas image to ajax

Tags: html2canvas

I am working in ASP.net. I can create an image using html2canvas of the div i want, but sending it through AJAX causes an error. The error statuscode is 'OK'. Not sure what that means. The serever side code never gets executed. The AJAX call I am making looks like this:

```
html2canvas($('#box1'), {

            onrendered: function (canvas) {



                $('#box1').html('');
                 $('#box1').append(canvas);
                cartImage = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');


                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: pageUrl + '/UploadImage',
                    data: { "imageData": cartImage },
                     dataType: "json",
                    success: function (msg) {
                       console.warn(msg.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {

                        console.warn(result.statusText);
                    }
                });
```

The server side code looks like this:

```
 Public Shared Function UploadImage(imageData) As String
    imageData = imageData.Replace("data:image/png;base64,", "")
    Dim fileNameWitPath As String = "TempDownload/" & Guid.NewGuid().ToString & ".png"
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create)
    Using (fs)
        Dim bw As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(fs)
        Using (bw)

            Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData) 'convert from base64
            bw.Write(data)
            bw.Close()
        End Using
    End Using
    Return "Success"
```

Answer (score 0):

I did find the AJAX call would work if I used JSON.stringify({ "imageData": cartImage }) for the data parameter in the AJAX call.